# how to implement these sidebar's correctly

Tags: html, css, user-interface, layout

Hi I'm trying to implement these layout and I'm trying to learn CSS , when I use `position: fixed;` the another one will overflow and this is my code:
[the layout picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqdbG.jpg)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #131211;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.side-bar {
  width: 7%;
  height: 96vh;
  background-color: #201f1e;
  margin: 1rem;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: fixed;
}

.side-menu {
  width: 20%;
  height: 60vw;
  margin: 7rem 2rem;
  background-color: #323130;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: inherit;
}

.card-container {
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/style.css">
  <title>ToDo</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="side-bar">sdasdsad</div>
    <div class="side-menu">sfgfdhsdfh</div>
    <div class="cards-container">sgjdfgjdfjdfjf</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you not want it to overflow? Could you clarify the question a bit please?

Comment: @daggett yes i want these two side bar stay fixed and the user scroll between cards